# Web Api File Param in Form always keeps being null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Im starting working with File Uploads in C# Web Api, currently the goal is to obtain the file from the Form-Param named **metaData**, this is how the file is handled inside the controller.

```
[HttpPost, Route("{applicationId}/Files"), ResponseType(typeof(List<int>))]
        [MimeMultiart]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CustomerApplicationFile(int applicationId)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get Data from form data.
                var stream = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferedInputStream();
                new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                var files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
                var metaData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["metaData"];

                // Create MultipartFormDataContent 
                var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
                {
                    {
                        new StringContent(metaData), "metaData"
                    }
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var key = files.AllKeys[i];
                    requestContent.Add(new StreamContent(files[i].InputStream), key, files[i].FileName);
                }
                // Get session key
                var sessionKey = await Uow.Users.GetSessionKey(GetUserId());

                string uri = string.Format(Constants.CustomerApplicationFiles, applicationId);
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sessionKey", sessionKey);
                    var response =
                        await client.PostAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + uri, requestContent);
                    return ResponseMessage(response);
                }
            }
            catch (BusinessEntityException ex)
            {
                Logger.Warn(ex);
                return this.BadRequest(ex);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex);
                return this.InternalServerError(AppError.ServerSqlNotFound);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex);
                return this.InternalServerError(AppError.InternalErrorServer);
            }
        }
```

However i keep receiving the followign message, saying that the parameter is null... but im sending as shown in this [image].

> "exceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException",
>         "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: content",
>         "stackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.StringContent.GetContentByteArray(String content,
>   Encoding encoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.StringContent..ctor(String
>   content, Encoding encoding, String mediaType)

Comment: If metaData is a file why don't you access it from the Files collection?

Comment: The file collection doesn't need any param related or work with a Context?